# Sink having access to objects of another instance of same class

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm having a problem with my kafka connector. I'm new to java so this might be a Java mistake Im making and not a kafka specific problem.

My Connector class is the following:

```
package org.MySink.influxSink;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.Task;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkConnector;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MySinkConnector extends SinkConnector {
  private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MySinkConnector.class);
  private Map<String, String> configProps;

  @Override
  public String version() {
    return VersionUtil.getVersion();
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Map<String, String> map) {
    try {
        configProps = map;
    } catch(ConfigException e) {
        throw new ConnectException("Couldn't start InfluxSinkConnector due to configuration error", e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Class<? extends Task> taskClass() {
    return MySinkTask.class;
  }

  @Override
  public List<Map<String, String>> taskConfigs(int maxTasks) {
    List<Map<String, String>> taskConfigs = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for(int i=0; i < maxTasks; i++) {
        taskConfigs.add(configProps);
    }
    

    return taskConfigs;

  }

  @Override
  public void stop() {
    return;
  }

  @Override
  public ConfigDef config() {
    return MySinkConnectorConfig.conf();
  }
}
```

And my task is the following:

```
package org.MySink.influxSink;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndMetadata;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkTask;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class MySinkTask extends SinkTask {
  private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MySinkTask.class);
  
  private String influxMeasurement;
  private MySinkConnectorConfig config;
  private Map<String, String> configMap;
  
  @Override
  public String version() {
    return VersionUtil.getVersion();
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Map<String, String> map) {
    config = new MySinkConnectorConfig(map);
    configMap = map;
    
    influxMeasurement = config.getInfluxMeasurement();

  }

  @Override
  public void put(Collection<SinkRecord> collection) {
      if(collection.isEmpty()) {
          return;
      }
      
      final SinkRecord first = collection.iterator().next();
      final int recordsCount = collection.size();
      

      log.info(influxMeasurement + ": Received {} records. First record Kafka coordinates: ({}-{}-{}).",
              recordsCount, first.topic(), first.kafkaPartition(), first.kafkaOffset());

  }

  @Override
  public void flush(Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> map) {

  }

  @Override
  public void stop() {
    //Close resources here.
  }

}
```

This is a simplified version of the connector that ilustrates the issue. The problem I was having was that I had two instances of the connector subscribed to two different problems. But whenever they would get published I would get the message:

```
kafka-connect              | 2022-12-04T16:21:06.431482588Z [2022-12-04 16:21:06,431] INFO ActiveSessions: Received 1 records. First record Kafka coordinates: (TotalSessions-0-1134). (org.MySink.influxSink.MySinkTask)
kafka-connect              | 2022-12-04T16:21:06.431530001Z [2022-12-04 16:21:06,431] INFO ActiveSessions: Received 1 records. First record Kafka coordinates: (ActiveSessions-0-1122). (org.MySink.influxSink.MySinkTask)
```

So, aparently both topics were going to the same connector and always the last one declared. After a lot of debugging I decided to change the line

```
log.info(influxMeasurement + ": Received {} records. First record Kafka coordinates: ({}-{}-{}).",
              recordsCount, first.topic(), first.kafkaPartition(), first.kafkaOffset());
  }
```

to

```
log.info(this.influxMeasurement + ": Received {} records. First record Kafka coordinates: ({}-{}-{}).",
              recordsCount, first.topic(), first.kafkaPartition(), first.kafkaOffset());
  }
```

And it resolved the issue as now I would get the message:

```
kafka-connect              | 2022-12-04T16:21:06.431482588Z [2022-12-04 16:21:06,431] INFO TotalSessions: Received 1 records. First record Kafka coordinates: (TotalSessions-0-1134). (org.MySink.influxSink.MySinkTask)
kafka-connect              | 2022-12-04T16:21:06.431530001Z [2022-12-04 16:21:06,431] INFO ActiveSessions: Received 1 records. First record Kafka coordinates: (ActiveSessions-0-1122). (org.MySink.influxSink.MySinkTask)
```

So, aparently, the messages were going to the right connectors but the variable influxMeasurement was changed on the first connector when the second one was declared. Does anyone have an idea why this might have happened?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a Java specific problem

- Each connector task (max.tasks) runs its own thread.
- Each thread runs its own instance of the Task class.
- You cannot share state directly between threads (Task instances), despite them being the same class. Adding `this` doesn't change anything  since you don't have a local variable of the same name.

Also, `put` is repeatedly called, based on Kafka Consumer polling. You'll need to **sum** the size of the collection (or batch data before writing to the database) to print any accurate count of records seen so far.